# Clarification of community scope

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I asked a question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/232319/automatic-adjusting-output-into-automatic-adjusting-input/) about two specific products and their use in conjunction with each other in an electronic circuit. The question was put on hold as off-topic, but I believe this was in error. In the defined community scope of reference, it clearly states

> This site is for electronics and electrical engineering

And electrical engineering is defined as

> a field of engineering that generally deals
>   with the study and application of electricity, electronics, and
>   electromagnetism

Therefore, asking about using two devices in conjunction with each other in an electric circuit is fully within the **community defined** scope.

If not, please do clarify.

Comment: Did you read the close reason, or did you stop right after reading "Off Topic"?

Comment: [Rules Lawyering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rules_lawyer) doesn't help you. As per Dave's answer - use of commercial products is off topic. And tbh, it's not engineering...

Comment: I understand the answer, but not your comments or the downvotes. I asked a simple, honest question here on meta and expected a simple, honest exchange.

Comment: Downvotes on meta indicate disagreement, not a bad question.

Comment: Oh, I always assumed they meant poor Q/A quality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but questions about the application of commercial products are specifically off-topic.

The reason for this is that without knowing anything about the design of the circuitry associated with the solar panel, it is impossible to infer anything about its behavior outside the applications specified by the manufacturer.

You would either have to get more detailed documentation from the manufacturer, or do some reverse-engineering in order to derive the information from the object itself. We WILL answer questions at this level, but you have to show significant effort and understanding on your own; otherwise, it becomes a hopeless case of "20 questions".

Comment: I totally agree concerning detailed documentation, but in a effort to better understand the rules, suppose the manufacturers had provided detailed datasheets as are provided with integrated circuits. Would it be on-topic then? I assume it would be on-topic if they were ICs? Is there and should there be a distinction between say a controller-board and an IC with regards to the rules?  They are both "commercial products", but I wouldn't really consider either "consumer electronics" which is what is actually mentioned in the rules.

Comment: ICs and modules DO come with detailed documentation on their internal operation and applications. The solar panel you referenced is most definitely a consumer electronics product. These two items are very different as far as our rules go.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not the OP. I agree and I did not reference the solar panel. The controller board did interest me as those type products do seem to be a little fuzzy concerning the rules.

Comment: @Tut: Ah, sorry, I didn't notice that. But yes, it's all about the documentation. If it's available, then any engineer can work out the behavior of the device (IC, module, etc.) from first principles. Without it, no one can, and we waste a lot of time trying to infer implementation from behavior and then extrapolating from there. If the OP doesn't have the skills and experience to understand our questions and gather the needed data, then the whole conversation devolves into a hopeless mess. The rule exists because the SE community in general has had plenty of experience with this in the past.